# Hide an element depending on the time of the CURRENT DAY

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, datetimepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using ui-datepicker calender from jquery, and i am trying to hide an element, option:nth-child(2), of the following options only on the current day before 10am:

```
<select name="delivery_time_frame" id="delivery_time_frame" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Choose a time of delivery ">                          
  <option value="">Choose a time of delivery </option>
  <option value="time_frame:0">12:00 – 14:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:1">14:00 – 16:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:2">16:00 – 18:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:3">18:00 – 20:00</option>                       
</select>
```

by using query selector:

```
document.querySelector("#delivery_time_frame > option:nth-child(2)")
```

for example, if the time is before 10:00am only on the current day i want to hide the first option. I dont want to hide if someone selects a date in the calender beyond the current day. For example if any following day is selected in the datepicker calender, i don't wont to hide the element; i want it visible for selection.

The point of this is if someone selects the same day to deliver in the calender, i want all options available (from 14:00 to 20:00) except the first.  If the select any other day to deliver i want all options available.

thanks for any help!

Comment: The selected date select must be part of the logic, where is that?

Answer (score 0):

I am not very clear with the exact scenario of your problem. Depending on provided information, it seems that you want to display different options of a DDL based on some condition. There may be few ways to solve such problem:

1. Prepare the options dynamically, depending on business logic using
   some loop(ex: for loop). Then assign it to the Select(DDL/Drop Down
   List control).
2. Display DDL with static options and add/remove class to show/hide
   options using a function to control display of options.
3. Prepare multiple DDL with static options and show a suitable DDL as
   required. It is not a recommended way but just a work around.

If I misunderstood your problem then please provide a screenshot describing the sequence of events and desired outcome.

Answer (score 0):

You should post a minimal example as code so that others can reproduce your issue as easily as possible. I've mocked up some supporting stuff, likely it's not what you have but is sufficient for an example.

I would disable the option rather than hide it so the user knows the option is there, just not available for the date they've selected (a message to that effect might help too).

There must be an associated date select to know what date the user has selected in order to enable or disable the option. That element needs a listener to modify options in the time select, e.g.

```js
// Helpers
function formatDate(date) {
  let z = n=>(n<10?'0':'')+n;
  return `${date.getFullYear()}-${z(date.getMonth()+1)}-${z(date.getDate())}`;
}
function parseISOLocal(s) {
  let [y,m,d] = s.split('-');
  return new Date(y, --m, d);
}

// Hide option if before 10 am today
function checkSelected() {
  // Get today's date
  let today = new Date();
  // Get date formatted for comparision with value in select
  let todayStamp = formatDate(today);
  // Get selected date
  let selectedDate = this.value; //document.getElementById('delivery_date').value
  // Get target option
  let opt = document.querySelector('#delivery_time_frame > option:nth-child(2)');
  // If it's today and before 10, hide option
  if (selectedDate == todayStamp && today.getHours() < 10) {
    console.log('disable ' + opt.value);
    opt.disabled = true;
    // Deselect in case it's been selected
    opt.selected = false;
  } else {
    opt.disabled = false;
    console.log('enable ' + opt.value);
  }
}

window.onload = function(){
  // Insert some dates in delivery_date
  let now = new Date();
  let select = document.getElementById('delivery_date');
  for (let i=0; i<3; i++) {
    let d = formatDate(now);
    select.appendChild(new Option(d, d));
    now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
  }
  // Attach listener on select
  let sel = document.querySelector('#delivery_date');
  if (sel) {
    sel.addEventListener('change', checkSelected, false);
  }
};
```

```html
<select name="delivery_date" id="delivery_date">
  <option selected>Select a delivery date
</select>
<select name="delivery_time_frame" id="delivery_time_frame" class="select " data-allow_clear="true" data-placeholder="Choose a time of delivery ">                          
  <option value="" selected>Choose a time of delivery </option>
  <option value="time_frame:0">12:00 – 14:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:1">14:00 – 16:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:2">16:00 – 18:00</option>
  <option value="time_frame:3">18:00 – 20:00</option>                   
</select>
```

It also needs to deal with whether the user has already selected a time or not (not attempted in the above as I don't know what other logic you need to implement).

You might also disable the time select until the user has selected a date.